# Multi-dimensional arrays with a named key?

Tags: php, python, arrays

I'm learning Python by converting some old scripts from PHP to Python, and I'm stuck with something I can solve in PHP.

I have 3 lists of data (fetched via SNMP). In PHP, I'm storing them like so:

```
  $array['12345']['user'] = 'example@example.com';
  $array['12345']['int_id'] = 1;
  $array['12345']['int_speed'] = 1238745;

  $array['51245']['user'] = 'example@example.com';
  $array['51245']['int_id'] = 2;
  $array['51245']['int_speed'] = 5151244;
```

As I have 3 lists, I'm doing 3 sets of processing. The first run fetches a list of all usernames and user IDs (12345/51245 above), meaning I can set the first part of the array. I can then process the other two lists of data, and in PHP they'd be assigned like so (in a foreach, probably):

```
  $array[$user_id]['int_id'] = $int_id;
  $array[$user_id]['int_speed'] = $int_speed;
```

Trying to replicate this behaviour on Python is becoming quite tricky, I'm presuming what I want to do is create a dictionary of lists? But then I'm not sure how I add/edit these lists or cycle through them getting all the values of each layer of the array in turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There don't seem to be any lists here at all; this is just a nested dict. And the syntax is pretty much the same as in PHP.

```
data = {}
for user_id in user_data:
    data[user_id] = {}
    data[user_id]['int_id'] = 1
    data[user_id]['user'] = 'foo@bar.com'

    # or more simply
    data[user_id] = {'user': 'foo@bar.com', 'int_id': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I was struggling so much. I've been doing PHP for years and years but only just picking up Python.